# installing google-fluentd agent on docker produce an error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, fluentd

I am trying to install google-fluentd agent on a docker and get the following error:

```
Restarting google-fluentd: google-fluentd ... failed!
```

The OS is Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Docker file snippet:

```
RUN cd /tmp && curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
RUN bash /tmp/install-logging-agent.sh
```

When i install it on a running docker image it works.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation script `install-logging-agent.sh` is trying to send a test message and fails since it does not have access to the IAM account at the point the docker image is built.

the testing phase.
The solution for me was to install the agent and ignore the error in docker and register the service to start when the docker image is running.
I guess another option will be to change the installation script.

It is a bit strange that the install script does not separate the installation phase and test phase.